# r convert Boolean vector to string

Tags: r, string, boolean

I would like to convert my vector y$boolean into a string indicating sentiment (0 to "negative" and 1 to "positive")

I imagine one way to do it is somehow using a Regex statement but not sure how to apply it

> dput(head(y$boolean,4)) = 
>   c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)

to

> y$sentiment = 
>   c("positive", "negative", "negative", "positive")

Comment: ifelse(y$boolean == 1, "positive", "negative")

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve you problem with 'Factor'

```
> vec <-  c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
> fac <- factor(vec, labels = c('negative', 'positive') )
> fac
[1] positive negative negative positive
Levels: negative positive
```

Note that you need to use 'negative' first because R will order the original vector and "0L" will be the first element to be assigned.

For example, let's change the integer vector to a character vector:

```
> vec_l <- c("b" , "a", "a", "b")
> fac_l <- factor(vec, labels = c("negative_a", "positive_b"))
> fac_l
[1] positive_b negative_a negative_a positive_b
Levels: negative_a positive_b
```

Now R orders the original vector alphabetically. 
"a" comes first, so you label "a" first with "negative_a" on the *labels* argument.